# How to get all of the input value using a class name in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#afiseaza_subtotal").click(function(){
            var i = 0; var list = []; 
            $(".name1").each(function(){
                list[i] =  $(this).val();
                i++;
            });
            var uniqueNames = [];
            $.each(list, function(i, el){
                if (el !=""){
                    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
                }
            });
            var html = "";
            if (uniqueNames.length > 0){
                $.each(uniqueNames, function(i, value){
                    var sum = 0;
                    if ($(".name1").attr("value") == value ){
                       // sum = parseFloat($(this).parent(".prod-persoana1").prev(".prod-pret1").find(".price").text());
                    }
                    //

                    html += "<p>Subtotal "+value+"-"+ sum +" lei </p>";

                });
                // initial_html = $(".subtotal").html();
                $(".subtotal").append(html);
            }else{
                alert("dasdasd");
            }
        });

    });
```

In the array uniqueNames i have all of the DISTINCT inputs value. I also another item where it is the sum. I want to get all of the **sum** value from the same **input**. See the example below:

```
 12$    Name1
 13.4$  Name2
 14$    Name1
 14$    Name3
```

the result will be a subtotal, which will look like this:

```
26$    Name1
13.4$  Name2
14$    Name3
```

As I said in the array uniuqNames I got the unique Names. Now I need to get the sum . How do I get the sum ?

This is the html code:

```
<div class="prod-pret1">
    <span class="price bolder">6.8 </span> Lei
</div>
<div class="prod-persoana1">
    <input name="nume1" type="text" id="nume1" class ="name1" value="" placeholder="Nume">
</div>
<div class="prod-pret1">
    <span class="price bolder">6.8 </span> Lei
</div>
<div class="prod-persoana1">
    <input name="nume2" type="text" id="nume2" class ="name1" value="" placeholder="Nume">
</div>
.....
```

Comment: If I m not making myself clear, please ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#afiseaza_subtotal").click(function(){
            $(".new_subtotal").each(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
            var i = 0; var list = []; 
            $(".name1").each(function(){
                list[i] =  $(this).val();
                i++;
            });
            var uniqueNames = [];
            $.each(list, function(i, el){
                if (el !=""){
                    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
                }
            });
            var html = "";
            if (uniqueNames.length > 0){
                $.each(uniqueNames, function(i, value){
                    var sum = 0;
                    $(".prod-pret1").each(function(){
                            initial_sum = parseFloat($(this).find(".price").text());

                            compare_value = $(this).next(".prod-persoana1").find(".name1").attr("value");
                            if (compare_value == value){
                                sum = sum + initial_sum;
                            }
                    });
                    html += "<p class='new_subtotal'>Subtotal "+value+"-"+ sum +" lei </p>";

                });
                // initial_html = $(".subtotal").html();
                $(".subtotal").append(html);
            }else{
                alert("dasdasd");
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You've overcomplicated:

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var subtotal = {};
    $('input').each(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
        var cls = this.className;
        if(subtotal[cls] === undefined){
             subtotal[cls] = parseFloat($this.val());   
        }
        else{
             subtotal[cls] += parseFloat($this.val());   
        }
    });
    
    console.log(subtotal);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="nume1" type="text" id="nume1" class ="name1" value="12" placeholder="Nume">
<input name="nume2" type="text" id="nume2" class ="name2" value="13.4" placeholder="Nume">
<input name="nume2" type="text" id="nume2" class ="name1" value="14" placeholder="Nume">
<input name="nume3" type="text" id="nume3" class ="name3" value="14" placeholder="Nume">    
<button>Calculate subtotal</button>
```

Output (to console):

> Object { name1=26, name2=13.4, name3=14}

Comment: Agreed.. thats way to overcomlicated html structure, as I already advised him to adopt more of a readable class structure.

Comment: @edduvs - it wasnt the html structure i meant was overcomplicated - html is html, its structured how it needs to be. What was overcomplicated was the javascript and the way it dealt with getting a unique set then trying to query it

Answer (score 0):

Well, this could easily be accomplished when you're pushing the unique name into the array.

```
 if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
```

Should actually run another block of code similar to this :

```
var subTotals = {};
if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) {

   $.each ( ELEMENTS_WITH_PRICES_FOR_CURRENT_NAME , function () {
      subTotals[el] += parseFloat($(this).parent(".prod-persoana"+el).prev(".prod-pret"+ el).find(".price").text())
   });

   uniqueNames.push(el);

}
```

`subTotals[ el ]` is being incremented with your `"formula"` of getting the price which is really wierd. You should really adopt other HTML structure. 
I can't really understand it. But the idea is similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#afiseaza_subtotal").click(function(){
        //Contains all the classes of the inputs and sum of their values
        var uniquenames = [];
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
             /*First time seeing this class, set value and key in array.*/
             if(uniquenames[$(this).class()] === "undefined")
             {
                 uniquenames[$(this).class()] = parseInt($(this).val());
             }
             else
             {
                 /*Add value in array*/
                 uniquenames[$(this).class()] += parseInt($(this).val());
             }
        });
        /*Use the uniquenames array in anyway you want :) The key = class; value = sum*/
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add").click(function () {
            var data = {};
            $("input[type='text']").each(function () {
                if (data[this.className] == undefined) {
                    data[this.className] = $("." + this.className).sum();
                }
            });
            $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
        });
    });

    (function ($) {
        $.fn.sum = function () {
            var s = 0.00;
            $(this).each(function () {
                s += Number($(this).val());
            });
            return s;
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" class="name1" value="14" />
    <input type="text" id="txt2" class="name1" value="14" />
    <input type="text" id="txt3" class="name2" value="14" />
    <input type="text" id="txt4" class="name3" value="14" />
</div>
<input type="submit" id="add" value="Calculate" />
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Output:

`{ "name1": 28, "name2": 14, "name3": 14 }`